# Issue exporting JSON data into a textfield

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using JSONDecoder protocol to get some data from a database.

Everything with the code below works as expected but I cannot get `car.driver_name` to export into a textfield called `contacttextField`

I have tried setting `self.contacttextField` = `car.driver_name` with poor results. For some reason, it takes about a minutes for the text from the decoded JSON to show up and the debugger says:

```
10  Foundation                          0x00000001d67a8908 <redacted> + 740
11  Foundation                          0x00000001d689ecec <redacted> + 272
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a436f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a44c74 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a47ffc _dispatch_continuation_pop + 524
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a47458 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 628
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a55dc8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 372
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000102a567ac _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d5a591b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001d5a5bcd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

**The following is the code I am using:**

```
struct FacilityInfo: Decodable {
    let driver_name: String
}

class infoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/test.php")!

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            // ensure there is no error for this HTTP response
            guard error == nil else {
                print ("error: \(error!)")
                return
            }

            // ensure there is data returned from this HTTP response
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data")
                return
            }

            // Parse JSON into array of Car struct using JSONDecoder

            guard let cars = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FacilityInfo].self, from: data) else {
                print("Error: Couldn't decode data into cars array")
                return
            }

            for car in cars {
                print("car name is \(car.driver_name)")
                self.usernameTextField.text = cars.driver_name
            }
        }

        task.resume()
```

Comment: Show your actual attempt to update the text field. Please remember that all UI updates must be done on the main queue.

Comment: I have updated my post, I do, `usernameTextField.text = cars.driver_name`

Comment: The text field will only show the last value. Don't try to set it in a loop. And again, you must do UI updates on the main queue.

Comment: What do you mean by main queue? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Can I move self.usernameTexfield.text = cars.driver_name?

Comment: Or maybe assign it to a variable? Will this help?

Comment: You have an array of cars. Which driver name do you want in the textfield?

Comment: There will always be one driver name given by the json depending on whatever parameter I add to the post request in a bit.

Comment: Please see the update I posted: driver_name is a string

Answer (score 0):

`URLSession.dataTask` executes its closure on a background thread, but all UI updates need to happen from the main thread. So you need to execute the call to `usernameTextField.text` on the main thread.

```
...
guard let cars = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FacilityInfo].self, from: data), let firstCar = cars.first else {
    print("Error: Couldn't decode data into cars array")
    return
}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.usernameTextField.text = firstCar.driver_name
}
```

Also keep in mind that `cars` is an array, so you should access one of its elements, which has a `driver_name` property and assign that to the textfield's `text` property. As an example, I've assigned the value from the first element, but change that to fit your requirements.

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names (`driverName`).